# i need a function that shows a users tree to be dynamic and not constrained to the manually set nodes array

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary-tree

So i have this JS function that returns a user's tree i.e referrals and their referrals too. the function works perfectly but the issue is that the function is limited to as many nodes as i indicate alphabetically. so i want the function dynamic and not constrained to the nodes i manually indicate

this function only displays nodes a - q

```
const showTreePage = async (id) => {
  var Settlement = [];

  Settlement.array_fill_keys = (keys, value) => {
    var retObj = {},
      key = "";
    for (key in keys) {
      retObj[keys[key]] = value;
    }
    return retObj;
  };

  let res = Settlement.array_fill_keys(
    {
      0: "b",
      1: "c",
      2: "d",
      3: "e",
      4: "f",
      5: "g",
      6: "h",
      7: "i",
      8: "j",
      9: "k",
      10: "l",
      11: "m",
      12: "n",
      13: "o",
      14: "p",
      15: "q",
    },
    []
  );
  res["a"] = await getUser(id);
  res["b"] = await getPositionUser(id, "left");
  if (res["b"] && res["b"].length > 0) {
    res["d"] = await getPositionUser(res["b"][0].id, "left");
    res["e"] = await getPositionUser(res["b"][0].id, "right");
  }
  if (res["d"] && res["d"].length > 0) {
    res["h"] = await getPositionUser(res["d"][0].id, "left");
    res["i"] = await getPositionUser(res["d"][0].id, "right");
  }
  if (res["e"] && res["e"].length > 0) {
    res["j"] = await getPositionUser(res["e"][0].id, "left");
    res["k"] = await getPositionUser(res["e"][0].id, "right");
  }
  
  res["c"] = await getPositionUser(id, "right");
  if (res["c"] && res["c"].length > 0) {
    res["f"] = await getPositionUser(res["c"][0].id, "left");
    res["g"] = await getPositionUser(res["c"][0].id, "right");
  }
  if (res["f"] && res["f"].length > 0) {
    res["l"] = await getPositionUser(res["f"][0].id, "left");
    res["m"] = await getPositionUser(res["f"][0].id, "right");
  }
  if (res["g"] && res["g"].length > 0) {
    res["n"] = await getPositionUser(res["g"][0].id, "left");
    res["o"] = await getPositionUser(res["g"][0].id, "right");
  }
  return res;
};
```

i need it to display nodes infinitely and not constrained to nodes (a-q)

Comment: This sort of thing is usually handled with a simple loop, iterating over your array values.

Comment: This code is not displaying anything? What is the purpose of the `Settlement` array since it never gets populated with anything? What will you use as key when you have arrived and used "z"? Why not numerical keys?